# Why is NSLayoutAttributeCenterX an 'Invalid pairing' with NSLayoutAttributeWidth

Tags: ios6, autolayout, nslayoutconstraint

I am trying to have the auto layout manager adjust the center point of a view, based on the width of the super view.  I don't understand why that is an 'Invalid Pairing' of the attributes (as told by the crash and NSInvalidArgumentException)

```
UIView *ac;
NSLayoutConstraint *cXloc = [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:ac 
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX 
                                                         relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual 
                                                            toItem:ac.superview 
                                                         attribute:NSLayoutAttributeWidth 
                                                        multiplier:.1 
                                                          constant:x*ac.superview.frame.size.width*.2];
[ac.superview addConstraint:cXloc];
```

Could someone explain why this is an 'Invalid paring' and how I should approach this?
Thanks

Comment: Really good question. Seems mysterious.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you relate ac's AttributeCenterX to its superview's AttributeCenterX, AttributeLeading, or AttributeTrailing, you should be able to express your desired constraint using the multiplier and constraint.  Keep in mind that the constant is evaluated only when the constraint is created, and your example's constant wouldn't update as ac.superview's width changes.

If you can express in words how you'd like ac positioned relative to its superview, we can suggest a constraint.

*Edit*

Here's an example with 5 NSButtons. They themselves and the space between them expand so that the spaces are 30% as wide as the buttons, all the buttons have the same width, and all the spaces have the same width. Creating 4 invisible NSViews just for spacing is pretty cumbersome, especially considering you've got it working outside of autolayout. But in case you're curious:

```
// Assuming these NSViews and NSButtons exist,
//NSView* superview ;
//NSButton *buttonOne, *buttonTwo, *buttonThree, *buttonFour, *buttonFive ;


[superView removeConstraints:superView.constraints] ;

// Create empty NSViews to fill the space between the 5 buttons.
NSView* spaceOne = [NSView new] ;
NSView* spaceTwo = [NSView new] ;
NSView* spaceThree = [NSView new] ;
NSView* spaceFour = [NSView new] ;
spaceOne.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO ;
spaceTwo.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO ;
spaceThree.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO ;
spaceFour.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO ;
[superView addSubview:spaceOne] ;
[superView addSubview:spaceTwo] ;
[superView addSubview:spaceThree] ;
[superView addSubview:spaceFour] ;

NSDictionary* views = NSDictionaryOfVariableBindings(superView,buttonOne,buttonTwo,buttonThree,buttonFour,buttonFive,spaceOne,spaceTwo,spaceThree,spaceFour) ;

// Vertically align buttonOne to its superview however you like.
[superView addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"V:|-[buttonOne]"  options:0  metrics:nil  views:views ] ] ;

// Make the "space" NSViews' widths equal and >= 10. Make the buttons' widths equal.
[superView addConstraints: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintsWithVisualFormat:@"H:|[buttonOne][spaceOne(>=10)][buttonTwo(==buttonOne)][spaceTwo(==spaceOne)][buttonThree(==buttonOne)][spaceThree(==spaceOne)][buttonFour(==buttonOne)][spaceFour(==spaceOne)][buttonFive(==buttonOne)]|"  options: NSLayoutFormatAlignAllCenterY  metrics:nil  views:views ] ] ;
// Make the "space" NSViews' widths 30% of the NSButtons' widths.
[superView addConstraint: [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem: spaceOne
                                                       attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                       relatedBy: NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                          toItem: buttonOne
                                                       attribute: NSLayoutAttributeWidth
                                                      multiplier: 0.3
                                                        constant: 0 ] ] ;
```

Comment: My goal is to layout 5 items horizontally in a superview with equal spacing between them.  The width of the objects should change with the width of the superview.  The aspect ratio of the subviews are constrained, so this leaves potential gap space which I want to all be equal.
I can't for the life of me figure out how to express this.  Additionally, I don't understand why CenterX can't be related to Width?
Lastly, the static nature of the equation is inherently undesired. Why can't I specify an equation or lazily computed expression?

Comment: So, the 5 items' widths should change with the superview. Does that mean the equal spacing between them will remain the same as the superview's width changes?

Comment: Not quite, everything should grow / shrink accordingly.  If I shrink the super view, each subview should also shrink.  As a result, this will adjust the spacing in between the views as well.  None of these values are fixed, they should all be dynamic.

I have broken down and done it manually, which was quite easy actually.  I still would like to know how / if it could be accomplished with constraints.

Answer (score 4):

It is the limitation of the current implementation of `Auto Layout`. However, you can easily work around it since all the constrains are linear and `NSLayoutAttribute`s are correlated. For example, say, the constraint you want is:

```
subview.centerX = m * superview.width + c;
```

You can express it as a relationship between tow `centerX`s:

```
// Since width == 2 * centerX
subview.centerX = m * 2 * superview.centerX + c;
```

Comment: You're assuming that `superview.width` is equal to `2 * superview.centerX`. Wouldn't that be true _only_ if `superview.frame.origin.x = 0`? CenterX is affected by the position of the view in its parent.

Comment: @an0: `superview.centerX = superview.leftX + superview.width/2` so it doesn't quite work. @glen-schmidt is correct

Answer (score 1):

Based on an0's answer, and assuming you have an NSArray containing your buttons, the following should space the buttons equally within the superview:

```
  NSUInteger currentButton = 1;
  for (UIButton *button in self.buttons)
  {
    [self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:button attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:self.view attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:2.0 * (CGFloat) currentButton / (CGFloat) (self.buttons.count + 1) constant:0.0]];
    currentButton++;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to have your programmatically generated views to fit its superview's width. You can use the constraint pairing of `NSLayoutAttributeLeading` and `attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX`

You have to make the proper calculation in order to get the right multiplier. Calculation involves the total count of the views to be laid out and the index of the current view.

```
    //Caculate constraint multiplier from parentView CenterX.
    //This sets the width of the button relative to parentView.
    // A value of 2 = Full width.

    CGFloat multiplier = 2/(arr.count/counter);

    [parentView addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:btn
                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                    relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual toItem:parentView
                    attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX multiplier:multiplier constant:0]];
```

This will distribute the views width to fill its superview.